# Set color for UNNotificationActionIcon(systemImageName: "circle")

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications

I want to set color for UNNotificationAction icon (UNNotificationActionIcon(systemImageName: "circle"))

I tried UNNotificationActionIcon(templateImageName: "redCircleFromAssetCatalog") with image from Asset catalog and the circle was red as expected.
But this is not a solution, because the color of the circle should be the user's choice, not the one that is already in the Asset Catalog

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot. It must be a template image, and iOS chooses a color in its own way.

Comment: @Sweeper maybe it's possible to generate an image of a circle in the chosen color, and then somehow use it as an image from the Asset Catalog?

Comment: You can try it. But it is not going to work.